# Is this function creating a new TensorFlow graph each time?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following [this tutorial](https://rdipietro.github.io/tensorflow-scan-examples/) on how to use `tf.scan` and I wrote a minimal working example (see code below). But each time the function `Model._step()` is called, isn't it creating another copy of the computational graph? If not, why not?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2' # to avoid TF suggesting SSE4.2, AVX etc...

class Model():
    def __init__(self):
        self._inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32)
        self._predictions = self._compute_predictions()

    def _step(self, old_state, new_input):
        # ---- In here I will write a much more complex graph ----
        return old_state + new_input

    def _compute_predictions(self):
        return tf.scan(self._step, self._inputs, initializer = tf.Variable(0.0))

    @property
    def predictions(self):
        return self._predictions

    @property
    def inputs(self):
        return self._inputs

def test(sess, model):
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(model.predictions, {model.inputs: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}))

test(tf.Session(), Model())
```

I'm asking because this is of course a minimal example, in my case I will need a much more complex graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Model._step()` method will only be called once per `Model` object constructed. The [`tf.scan()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan) function, like the [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) function it wraps, will call their given function(s) only once to build a graph with a loop in it, and then the same graph will be used for each iteration of the loop.

(Note that if you construct many `Model` objects you will end up with the same number of copies of the graph as you have `Model` objects.)

Comment: Thank you. I thought `tf.scan()` would have called `Model._step()` on each element of `Model.inputs`.